whatsapp://send must be sent two times to actually works
I'm trying to implement a whatsapp://send (wa.me) link in my project, but the first time I add the parameters (number + text), it only opens the WhatsApp chat, and the text itself doesn't appear. Only the second time I send the whatsapp://send request does my text appear. I don't want to send this message through WhatsappWeb, it must be through the Desktop App.
The interesting thing about it is, if the chat window has already been opened, then the message appears on the first try, otherwise i must send the request 2 times
I tried looking at Whatsapp documentation and used 1-whatsapp://send + parameters 2-wa.me/ + parameters. I tried using the Beta and Stable versions of the app from Microsoft Store.
